# ASP.NET picture gallery

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gallery, image-gallery

I wanted to ask for an advice regarding picture gallery... The users on the website I'm working on should be able to add pictures into the gallery which will be displayed on public part of the website... I was wondering if the pictures which the users add should go to DB or file system?  I understand that adding all those pictures to the DB would overload it  and the DB would loose on its performance, so I was wondering what is the best way to handle this in ASP.NET? Is it by uploading the pictures to the file system or? What are best solutions? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its most basic form you need to create a form to upload images.

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='handler.aspx' method="POST">
    <input type='file' name='image' />
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now when user selects a file and clicks on Submit button file will be uploaded to server and form will be submitted. After appropriate validation and file checking, you can move file to some directory and save its path and name in your database.

When creating gallery just read file path from database and display image using `img` tag. Set `src` attribute of `img` tag to file path read from database.

You should look at this series [File Upload with ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1757/File-Upload-with-ASP-NET)